# Installing dropbox-api on SUSE fails

Tags: linux, installation, dropbox, perl, api

I am trying to install the dropbox-api onto my suse 11.4 but i keep getting this error:

> Can't locate DateTime.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3 /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3 .) at /root/bin/dropbox-api line 6.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/bin/dropbox-api line 6.

At first I thought it lacked some perl modules so I went ahead and installed some CPAN modules along with the CPAN shell using

```
#perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

So through the shell I installed the extra modules like

```
# install DateTime::TimeZone
```

But still I get the same error. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong or what's wrong? I am using [these instructions](https://github.com/s-aska/dropbox-api-command) to install the API.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install `DateTime::Format::Strptime` ? It has `DateTime` as a dependency so it should have been installed.

Try running the following test to verify that DateTime is installed:

```
$ perl -MDateTime -e1
```

The test is successful if it does not produce any output; a message like `Can't locate DateTime.pm in @INC <...>` means DateTime wasn't found in the library search paths.

Did you use `cpanm` to install `DateTime::Format::Strptime` ? if you used the cpan shell, make sure you said 'yes' to 'follow dependencies', so that dependencies for a module are installed automatically.

Are you using `perlbrew` or `local::lib`? Either tool can cause a module to be installed to non-standard locations, such that programs cannot find them (unless they are also run with `local::lib` or `perlbrew`.

Failing all of the above, what is the output of running:

```
$ echo DateTime | perl -MFile::Spec -nE'BEGIN { say STDERR qq{Searching "${ \join(q{", "}, @INC)}"} } chomp; for my $dir ( @INC ) { my $module_file = File::Spec->catfile( $dir, split /::/, $_ ) . qq{.pm}; say $module_file if -e $module_file; }'
```